# Sort array on a nested property

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, nested, jq

I have this json in a file

```
{
    "items" : [
        {
            "status" : {
                "phase": "Failed",
                "startTime": "2020-11-15T15:42:26Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "status" : {
                "environments": [
                    {
                        "dev": "test"
                    }
                ],
                "phase": "Running",
                "startTime": "2020-11-17T15:42:26Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "status" : {
                "environments": [
                    {
                        "dev": "test2"
                    }
                ],
                "phase": "Running",
                "startTime": "2020-11-10T15:42:26Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to order this json based on startTime, I want to return the list ordered by the latest date.
I tried this query
`jq -r '.items[].status | sort_by(.startTime)'`

but it gives the following error:
 `jq: error (at <stdin>:4399): Cannot index string with string "startTime"`

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.items | sort_by(.status.startTime) | map(.status) | reverse
```

Where:

1. Take out `.items`
2. Sort items on the `.status.startTime` (ascending order)
3. Then for each item only keep status
4. And finally reverse the list

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "environments": [
      {
        "dev": "test"
      }
    ],
    "phase": "Running",
    "startTime": "2020-11-17T15:42:26Z"
  },
  {
    "phase": "Failed",
    "startTime": "2020-11-15T15:42:26Z"
  },
  {
    "environments": [
      {
        "dev": "test2"
      }
    ],
    "phase": "Running",
    "startTime": "2020-11-10T15:42:26Z"
  }
]
```